# Mysql Match date

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called `promotions`

Already inserted data:

```
COLUMNS             VALUE
`startdate`         15-03-2014 00:00:00
`enddate`           30-05-2014 00:00:00
`promotion_for`     1 (product_id)
```

New query for insert data

```
COLUMNS             VALUE
`startdate`         15-03-2014 00:00:00
`enddate`           30-05-2014 00:00:00
`promotion_for`     1 (product_id)
```

I don't want to insert new promotion if already promotion running in same product with during insert date.

No idea how to generate MySQL query for it.

Comment: you have to check with PHP if there is an active promotion for your dates

Comment: @LaurynasMališauskas i want to do it with mysql query but it will be heavy script for future to get all products of 1(product id) and check with php

Answer (score 0):

First add unique key to `promotions`:

```
ALTER TABLE `promotions` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX(`startdate`,`enddate`,`promotion_for`);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO `promotions` ( `startdate`,`enddate`,`promotion_for`)
VALUES ('15-03-2014 00:00:00', '30-05-2014 00:00:00', '1') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE `startdate`='15-03-2014 00:00:00', `enddate`='30-05-2014 00:00:00', `promotion_for` = '1';
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i want, i just thrown an error to user if a promotion already running.

Comment: @user3359090 You can remove "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." from my answer and check the returned value of the query in php. Depends on what php-sql class you are using (mysql_query() returnes false if not inserted)